# Is It Acceptable to Name Your Daughter Muhammad?

Tags: halal-haram, prophets, naming

If I wished to name my daughter Muhammad in honour of the Prophet (pbuh), I know it would not be a haram thing to do, but would it be acceptable?  Muhammad would be her first name/given name.

Comment: If it's not Haram then why can't it be acceptable?. Usually daughters are named including atleast one feminine name, so are you planning to name just Muhammad or is it going to be like a last name or first name?.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have now modified my question in the light of your query.

Comment: Yes it would be acceptable, but why would you name your daughter a man's name. Usually girls are named feminine names.

Comment: One is asked to chose an appropriate name and Muhammad is clearly a masculine name.

Comment: You better should not do it whether allowed or not because your daughter will always be addressed to as a man and explain why she has a male name

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, Muhammad is a masculine name. Although from a jurisprudential point of view, you are not specifically forbidden from doing so. But for example, as soon as you give your daughter a masculine name, you have done something useless and you have deviated from the right path. You can put the name of the Prophet's mother or wife on your daughter to honor the character of the Prophet of Islam. This is more worthy and closer to the right path.

https://fa.wikifeqh.ir/%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%85%E2%80%8C%DA%AF%D8%B0%D8%A7%D8%B1%DB%8C_%DA%A9%D9%88%D8%AF%DA%A9

Answer (score 0):

It's not forbidden, but neither the Prophet nor his Companions called their daughters with men names, and this is to respect the feminine nature Allah created them with.

They deserve a girl's name, so give them what Allah willed for them to have:

> فَلَمَّا وَضَعَتْهَا قَالَتْ رَبِّ إِنِّي وَضَعْتُهَا أُنثَىٰ
> وَاللَّهُ أَعْلَمُ بِمَا وَضَعَتْ وَلَيْسَ الذَّكَرُ كَالْأُنثَىٰ ۖ
> وَإِنِّي سَمَّيْتُهَا مَرْيَمَ وَإِنِّي أُعِيذُهَا بِكَ
> وَذُرِّيَّتَهَا مِنَ الشَّيْطَانِ الرَّجِيمِ
>
> ( 3/36 )   *But when she delivered her, she said, "My Lord, I have
> delivered a female." And Allah was most knowing of what she delivered,
> "**And the male is not like the female.** And I have named her Mary, and I
> seek refuge for her in You and [for] her descendants from Satan, the
> expelled [from the mercy of Allah]."*

Answer (score 0):

AsSalaamu Alaikum

Masha Allah on the birth of your daughter! By now you have a name so this is for anyone who comes accross this Islamic thread on naming.

Jabir ibn Abdullah (may Allah be pleased with him) reported that the Prophet (pbuh) said:

Whoever has three daughters and he accommodates them, show mercy toward them, and supports them, Paradise is definitely guaranteed for him.

https://aboutislam.net/shariah/hadith/hadith-collections/5-hadiths-girl-children/

Consider to ask your imam about naming your daughter Fatimah Muhammad or Amatullah Muhammad, or Hameeda Muhammad, insha Allah. I was told by our Imam that the best names are the names of the sahabah.

Prophet Muhammad SAWS said the best name is Abdullah. He (SAWS) also said, name your children after prophets.

Also if you have a son one day, you could name him Muhammad and in our Imams family every boy has the name Muhammad followed by a second name and then the surname. I enjoy looking at names these two websites:

1. http://companions.hawramani.com/
2. https://quranicnames.com/quranic-names-directly-mentioned-in-the-quran/

And Allah knows best